# Is the "Screen Blur in dialogues" after TW3 1.30 a known bug?

Tags: ps4, the-witcher-3

**ALL OF THIS ON PS4**
A few weeks ago, an update for The Witcher 3 `(v1.30)`  has been published. The log states several bug fixes, and **a look change for the banker *Vivaldi.***

The only problem right now is that when I am near Hierarch Square's Vivaldi's bank or in general Novigrad, at every dialog the whole screen blurs, and a loading icon pops up. This does not only happen when I start a dialogue, but also evertime Geralt says something.

I'd like to know if there are articles, official tweets, posts (e.g. We found a bug, will be fixed soon!) or if the company and/or IGN and other sites have officially defined this as a found bug. Also, for some awkward reason, Vivaldi's arm are invisible too.

On several forums, I found other users talking about this issue. All of them are on either PS4 or XBOX One. It seems that users who HAVE purchased *Hearts of Stone* and *Blood and Wine* are NOT experiencing this bug, and Vivaldi's arms are visible. Hmm...

Comment: why are you yelling at me? in bold?

Comment: "I'd like to know if there are articles, official tweets, posts" Can I just say "no", and leave it at that? Seriously tough, I rather dislike this sort of questions. Mostly because prooving non-existance is a big pain, if not impossibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer online:
**Yes, it is.**
CD Projekt RED is working at a fix and will release it soon in the 1.31 patch.
Source: http://thewitcher.com/en/news/view/2501